# React + Typescript: How to type event.target.name to state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have som react state that was defined as an interface and has specificall named keys...

I tried a solution below that should technically work based on the state keys, but it still gives me the error

```
{ [x: string]: string; }' provides no match for the signature  ...
```

What is the best way to do this...

```
interface State {
    responses: string,
    comments: string,
}


  state = {
    responses: '',
    comments: '',
  };

  handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, value: string): void => {
    const key = e.currentTarget.name;
    Object.keys(this.state).forEach(k => {
      if (k === key) this.setState({ [e.currentTarget.name]: value });
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The return type of `Object.keys()` is the generic `string[]` rather than an array of the union of the keys of the object, so it's probably tricky to infer the correct types here. Moreover, in my experience, smart solutions have a tendency to break when newer versions of TypeScript or package type definitions are released, so in this case I would just help TypeScript with a signature on to the argument of `setState`:

```
handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, value: string): void => {
  const key = e.currentTarget.name;

  if (Object.keys(this.state).includes(key)) {
    this.setState({[key]: value } as Pick<State, keyof State>);
  }
}
```

Comment: nice this is exactly what I was looking for. I knew there had to be a simple way to do something like that. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way for this when not all values in the state have the type string? I have booleans as well and that obviously does not work here.

Answer (score 3):

```
public onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  this.setState({
    [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value
  } as { [K in keyof IState]: IState[K] });
};
```

`IState` - interface of `this.state`

Comment: a couple of notes about your answer and how it solves the OP's question would be beneficial. Read [answer]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I think the code doesn't need more comments than what is below

Answer (score 2):

One option would be instead of iterating through keys, to use switch statement. Although it will produce more code:

```
switch (key) {
  case 'responses':
    this.setState({ responses: value });
    break;
  case 'comments':
    this.setState({ comments: value });
    break;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way? My state object is actually much larger, I just cut it down for the question

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and had to use this approach, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare state with type number then use this code for update state:

```
 this.setState({ ...this.state, [event.currentTarget.name]: Number(event.target.value) });
```

If you declare state with type string then use this code for update state:

```
this.setState({ ...this.state, [event.currentTarget.name]: event.target.value });
```

Full code:

```
onChange =(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            this.setState({ ...this.state, [event.currentTarget.name]: Number(event.target.value) });
        }
```