# How to type name and value from event.target in change handler

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326461/react-typescript-how-to-type-event-target-name-to-state), but none of the answers there solved my problem. I have a simple form with named inputs that correspond to values in a React component's state. The component has a change handler that updates the state accordingly when an input's value is changed:

```
interface State {
  name: string,
  email: string,
  address: string,
  zip: string,
}

class Form extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    name:'',
    email: '',
    address: '',
    zip: '',
  };

  handleChange = ({ target }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

However, Typescript gives me the following error:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<State, "name" | "email" | "address" | "zip">': name, email, address, zip.
```

As noted above, I tried the following solutions:

```
handleChange = ({ target }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  const { name, value } = target;

  if (Object.keys(this.state).indexOf(name) > -1) {
    this.setState({ [name]: value } as Pick<State, keyof State>);
  }
}

handleChange = ({ target }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  const { name, value } = target;
  this.setState({ [name]: value } as { [K in keyof State]: State[K] });
}
```

but neither solution worked. Is there another way to type the name & value?

Comment: Why didn't `this.setState({ [name]: value } as Pick<State, keyof State>);` work, it should..

Comment: I get `Conversion of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' to type 'Pick<State, "name" | "email" | "address" | "zip">' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<State, "name" | "email" | "address" | "zip">': name, email, address, zip.`